# Does redis3 cluster support socket connections?

Tags: redis

I'm running redis-3.0.4 in cluster mode. the os is centos6.6 x86_64

```
10.0.0.1:6379 master, 10.0.0.1:6380 slave
10.0.0.2:6379 master, 10.0.0.2:6380 slave
10.0.0.3:6379 master, 10.0.0.3:6380 slave
```

all the 6 processes are listening both tcp and unixsocket.

when I connect to the cluster via tcp, it works. all the operations are okay.

but when I save keys into the cluster via unixsocket, it throws out:

```
exception 'myfilename' with message 'Redis error: MOVED 6118 10.0.0.2:6379
```

I tested it on command line via:

```
redis-cli -c -s /tmp/redis-6379.sock
redis /tmp/redis-6379.sock> set hello world
```

it throws out a lot of:

```
...
-> Redirected to slot [3300] located at 10.0.0.3:6379
...
```

(it doesn't stop till I pressed ctrl+c)

How can I use a socket to connect to the redis3 cluster?